# Validar datos de entrada en un array de inputs html ,usando javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Estaba tratando de hacer la validación de 3 diferentes arrays de inputs antes de procesarlos, donde cada uno contiene 2 tipos de datos: una nota o calificación y un núm. de inasistencias. Pero solo interesa hacer validación en la nota o calificación, ingresada: que sea entre el rango de 5-10  (Deje en la condición:  if  ( (p < 5 && p != 0.0) ) , porque en la tabla de la bd. el campo de nota o evaluación es de tipo decimal y aparece 0.0 como por default, y este valor es recuperado asi en el formulario.)

Aquí un ejemplo en php de como funcionan los arreglos, de lo que intentaba hacer pero con js. http://rextester.com/TVBDL6264

Intentaba hacer la validación de esta forma, pero no la ejecuta creo que estaré mal desde la forma de llamar la función:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function validaForm() {
   var p1 = document.getElementsByName('parcialP1[]');
   var p2 = document.getElementsByName('parcialP2[]');
   var p3 = document.getElementsByName('parcialP3[]');
     // estructura: un solo arreglo contiene dos tipo de dato: nota e inasistencias 
    // nota,           inasistencias    nota             inasistencias
   // parcialP1[0]=4,  parcialP1[2]=3,  parcialP1[3]=9,  parcialP1[4]=1
   for ( var i=1; n = p1.length; i < n; i +=2) {  //pre-incremento de 2  y bucle para primer parcial
    
         var p = p1[i-1].value; //recorre una posision en el array qe corresponda al dato: nota
         if  ( (p < 5 && p != 0.0) || (p > 10) ) {  
             alert("Nota Ingresada NO Invalida, Por Favor Ingrese Valor entre 5 y 10");
             p1.focus(); //que pusiera un focus sobre el elemnto input del array que detecta como no valido
             return false;
         }
       }

      for ( var i=1; n = p2.length; i < n; i +=2) {  //pre-incremento de 2  y bucle para primer parcial
    
         var p = p2[i-1].value; 
         if  ( (p < 5 && p != 0.0) || (p > 10) ) {  
             alert("Nota Ingresada NO Invalida, Por Favor Ingrese Valor entre 5 y 10");
             p2.focus(); //que pusiera un focus sobre el elemnto input del array que detecta como no valido
             return false;
         }
       }

       for ( var i=1; n = p3.length; i < n; i +=2) {  //pre-incremento de 2  y bucle para primer parcial
    
         var p = p3[i-1].value; 
         if  ( (p < 5 && p != 0.0) || (p > 10) ) {  
             alert("Nota Ingresada NO Invalida, Por Favor Ingrese Valor entre 5 y 10");
             p3.focus(); //que pusiera un focus sobre el elemnto input del array que detecta como no valido
             return false;
         }
       }
 }
</script>
```

```html
 <form method="POST" action="Capt_Calif.php" onsubmit="return validaForm();">
          <td><input type="text" name="parcialP1[]" class="p1" size="2" value="<?php echo $alumno[2]; ?>" ></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="parcialP1[]" class="p1" size="2" value="<?php echo $alumno[3]; ?>" ></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="parcialP2[]" class="p2" size="2" value="<?php echo $alumno[4]; ?>" ></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="parcialP2[]" class="p2" size="2" value="<?php echo $alumno[5]; ?>" ></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="parcialP3[]" class="p3" size="2" value="<?php echo $alumno[8]; ?>" ></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="parcialP3[]" class="p3" size="2" value="<?php echo $alumno[9]; ?>" ></td>
        </tr>
            </tbody>
           </table>   
           <div align="center"> 
           <button type="submit" name="formAlumno" id="enviar" class="btn btn-success" >CAPTURAR EVALUACIONES</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo haber leído esta pregunta en alguna ocasión. A simple vista, lo primero que noto es que `document.getElementsByName` recibe como parámetro un `string` con el nombre de los elementos que quieres obtener mientras que tú estás pasando una variable sin definir. Luego en las declaraciones `var p = px[i-1]` debes usar la propiedad value para acceder al valor, así: `var p = p2[i-1].value`.

Comment: de acuerdo, gracias.Entonces ¿ esta mal la parte de: document.getElementsByName , Como deberia ser?

Comment: Si quieres obtener los elementos con nombre parcialP1[] debes indicarlo así: `document.getElementsByName('parcialP1[]')`

Comment: ya lo cambie, pero todavía no ejecuta la función. ¿No estará fallando la forma de llamar la función en el form, o alguna otra cosa?

Comment: Estás teniendo un problema en el bucle for, en lugar de `for (var i=1; n = p1.length; i < n; i +=2)` debes usar `for ( var i=1, n = p1.length; i < n; i +=2)` (reemplaza el primer punto y coma por coma)

Comment: si es cierto, ya entra en el bucle gracias, disculpa la molestia 2 preguntas mas. 
1¿como hacer que haga un focus sobre el campo que que encuentra como no valido?
2. Y la dar clic en aceptar al alert lanzadoo, el formulario aún asi lo procesa, ¿como hacer que esto no pase y se quede en la misma pagina, desde donde se quedo la captura?

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es de sintaxis. El for tiene tres partes definidas y separadas por un ;. En el caso de tu for, hay cuatro...

Comment: Hola @Isaac. Creo que una respuesta de esta índole ser vería beneficiada con el fragmento de código corregido